# adjust the table on the next page

Tags: tables, positioning, height

i have question for table in the next page

i hope my table like this (ms. word) :

[image]

why when i compile be like this :

[image]

my code :

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Spektrogram digit 0-9}
\label{tab:contohtabel1}

\begin{tabular}{|p{10cm}|p{3.5cm}|}
\hline
Pengucapan kata 'Nol'. Nama file diberi label '- 0' untuk menandai data suara digit. &
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=35mm, height=22mm]{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}
\end{minipage} \\
\hline
Pengucapan kata 'Satu'. Nama file diberi label '- 1' untuk menandai data suara digit. &
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=35mm, height=22mm]{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}
\end{minipage}\\
\hline
Pengucapan kata 'Dua'. Nama file diberi label '- 2' untuk menandai data suara digit. &
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=35mm, height=22mm]{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}
\end{minipage}\\
\hline
Pengucapan kata 'Tiga'. Nama file diberi label '- 3' untuk menandai data suara digit. &
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=35mm, height=22mm]{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}
\end{minipage}\\
\hline
Pengucapan kata 'Empat'. Nama file diberi label '- 4' untuk menandai data suara digit. &
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=35mm, height=22mm]{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}
\end{minipage}\\
\hline
Pengucapan kata 'Lima'. Nama file diberi label '- 5' untuk menandai data suara digit. &
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=35mm, height=22mm]{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}
\end{minipage}\\
\hline
Pengucapan kata 'Enam'. Nama file diberi label '- 6' untuk menandai data suara digit. &
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=35mm, height=22mm]{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}
\end{minipage}\\
\hline
Pengucapan kata 'Tujuh'. Nama file diberi label '- 7' untuk menandai data suara digit. &
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=35mm, height=22mm]{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}
\end{minipage}\\
\hline
Pengucapan kata 'Delapan'. Nama file diberi label '- 8' untuk menandai data suara digit. &
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=35mm, height=22mm]{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}
\end{minipage}\\
\hline
Pengucapan kata 'Sembilan'. Nama file diberi label '- 9' untuk menandai data suara digit. &
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=35mm, height=22mm]{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}
\end{minipage}\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Normal `tabular`s do not break across pages. You might wanto to give a look e.g. at the  `longtable` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}    % in real document remove option "demo"
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % for positioning image in cells
\newcommand\insertimage[1]{%     shortcuts for inserting images 
\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth,height=22mm, valign=t,margin=0pt 2pt 0pt 2pt]{#1}}
\usepackage{ltablex}           % combination of tabularx and longtable

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| X | c |}
\caption{Spektrogram digit 0-9}
\label{tab:contohtabel1}                    \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{Spektrogram digit 0-9 (cont.)}     \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize    continue on the next page}
\endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
Pengucapan kata 'Nol'. Nama file diberi label '- 0' untuk menandai data suara digit.
    &   \insertimage{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}  \\
    \hline
Pengucapan kata 'Satu'. Nama file diberi label '- 1' untuk menandai data suara digit.
    &   \insertimage{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}  \\
    \hline
Pengucapan kata 'Dua'. Nama file diberi label '- 2' untuk menandai data suara digit.
    &   \insertimage{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}  \\
    \hline
Pengucapan kata 'Tiga'. Nama file diberi label '- 3' untuk menandai data suara digit.
    &   \insertimage{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}  \\
    \hline
Pengucapan kata 'Empat'. Nama file diberi label '- 4' untuk menandai data suara digit.
    &   \insertimage{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}  \\
    \hline
Pengucapan kata 'Lima'. Nama file diberi label '- 5' untuk menandai data suara digit.
    &   \insertimage{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}  \\
\hline
Pengucapan kata 'Enam'. Nama file diberi label '- 6' untuk menandai data suara digit.
    &   \insertimage{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}  \\
    \hline
Pengucapan kata 'Tujuh'. Nama file diberi label '- 7' untuk menandai data suara digit.
    &   \insertimage{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}  \\
    \hline
Pengucapan kata 'Delapan'. Nama file diberi label '- 8' untuk menandai data suara digit.
    &   \insertimage{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}  \\
    \hline
Pengucapan kata 'Sembilan'. Nama file diberi label '- 9' untuk menandai data suara digit.
    &   \insertimage{figures/spektrogram0.jpg}  \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]